# Downloading multiple items in package

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

I need to allows users to download multiple images in a single download.  This download will include an sql file and images.  Once the download completes, the sql will execute, inserting text into an sqlite database.  This text will include references to the download images.  The text and images are rendered in a UIWebView.

What is the best way to download everything in a single download?  I was thinking to use a bundle since it can be loaded at runtime but not sure of any limitations/restrictions in this scenario.  I have tested putting the bundle into the Documents folder and then accessing resources inside of it.  That seems to work fine in a simple test.

Answer (score 0):

You're downloading everything through a socket, which only knows about bytes, so a bundle, or even a file, doesn't "naturally" transfer through, the server side opens files and encodes and sends them into the connection, the client reads from the socket and reconstructs the original file structure.

Assuming the application has a UI for picking which items needs to be transferred, it could then request all items to the server, and the server could then send all the items through the single connection with some delimitation you invent, so that the iPhone app can split the stream back into the individual files.

Or another options is that the client could just perform individual HTTP requests for the different files, through pretty straightforward use of [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/index.html).

The former sounds like an attempt to optimize the latter. Have you already tested and verified that the latter is too slow/inefficient? It definitely is more complex to implement.

There is a latency issue with multiple HTTP connections that you run in a sequence, however you can perhaps mitigate it by running multiple downloads connections in parallel -- for example through an [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/index.html) with a limit of 2 to 5 concurrent download operations.